# How can i reduce the size of a table stores long text in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with some nvarchar(MAX) columns in sqlserver.

Now, most of these columns are storing a few hundred lines of text, which make the table taking up a lot of disk space.

How can i reduce the size of the table, may be change the type of the columns, without losing data?

Comment: The only other data type you could *realistically* change the column to would be a `varchar`, and ***only*** if you can guarantee that no characters outside of the collations code page is in the existing data, nor will need to be. "A few hundred lines" of text doesn't mean anything though; how wide is a line? If it's just 100 characters (lie your first full line in the question), then you have 100x100 characters, giving you a total of 10,000 characters and 20,000 bytes (plus a small amount of overhead). 2KB is not really a lot. Is the data *really* has large in storage size as you think?

Comment: You can use [`COMPRESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) potentially to store a compressed version rather than as plain text

Comment: Thank you, I think I must explain some of them are even thousands lines of text. I tried to cast the text to varbinary, but it didn't work very well

Comment: How many rows are we talking about, how big are we talking about, how is that size broken out among data/index? What is `AVG(DATALENGTH(col))`? Is the table a heap and has it gone through a lot of updates/deletes? Is this long column part of include columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data doesn't have any unicode characters, you could use [varchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#character-strings)(max), that uses half the space of nvarchar(max). But if you have unicode characters, they will be replaced by '?', so you would lose data.

The other option you have is to activate [data compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-ver15) on the table. You can do this on the Data Compression Wizard of SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Results of data compression may be disappointing. Unicode compression is not supported for `nvarchar(max)` data even if it is stored in row so to get any benefit would need to use page compression (row compression would have no effect) - for page compression it depends whether the data is stored in row or not whether it is actually compressed

Answer (score 0):

It is worth considering the possibility of using a clustered columnstore index on a table since it provides a high data compression ratio.

For example:

```
Create Table [dbo].[Tbl] (ID Int Identity(1,1), Txt nVarChar(max))

Declare @Cnt Int = 0
Declare @LowerNum Int = 500
Declare @UpperNum Int = 8000
Declare @Length Int

-- filling in the table with data

While @Cnt < 20000
    Begin 
        Select @Length = Round(((@UpperNum - @LowerNum) * Rand()) + @LowerNum, 0)

        Insert Into [dbo].[Tbl] (Txt)
        Select Txt
        From OpenJson((Select Txt From (Select crypt_gen_random(@Length) As Txt) As R For Json Auto)) With (Txt nVarChar(max))

        Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    End
```

Сreating a clustered primary key on the [ID] column.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tbl] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
        FILLFACTOR = 90, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)
ON [PRIMARY]
```

The size of the table in this case is about 250MB.

Let's create a clustered columnstore index instead of a clustered primary key.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [PK_Tbl] ON [dbo].[Tbl] WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now the size of the table is about 135MB.